# Plot not visible in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib notebook
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()

def animate(i):
    x_vals.append(next(index))
    y_vals.append(random.randint(0, 5))
    
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vals,y_vals)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval = 1000)
    

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am expecting to see the live graph but I get <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> as an output.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` to your imports

Comment: I have already imported that in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: try pasting this into your notebook %matplotlib inline

Comment: I don't know why it is still not working. I imported both the things you suggested. I'll have to find some other alternatives.